# How to get TypeSyntax from TypeDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, roslyn

I'm writing a simple Roslyn generator that generates an interface implementation so I want to get `TypeSyntax` from `TypeDeclarationSyntax`, because of following code:

```
// Our generator is applied to any class that our attribute is applied to.
var applyToInterface = (InterfaceDeclarationSyntax)applyTo;

// Trying to implement this interface
var clientClass = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(applyToInterface.Identifier.ValueText + "Client"))
    .WithModifiers(SyntaxTokenList.Create(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
    .WithBaseList(SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(applyToInterface.???));
```

However, I don't see any way to create TypeSyntax except `SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName`. But I don't want to get interface name and then convert it back to type, because of possible bugs (like `+` chars in generics instead of dot and so on).

What is the most convinient and recommended way to perform this operation? Currently I'm using

```
var clientClass = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(applyToInterface.Identifier.ValueText + "Client"))
    .WithModifiers(SyntaxTokenList.Create(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
    .AddBaseListTypes(SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(applyToInterface.Identifier.ValueText)));
```

But i'm not sure if it's correct always.

Comment: as you know Roslyn is one of the least documented project, please clarify your because of the following code.  You want to type syntax so you can use it in the with base list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the way you are doing it is correct, Due to Roslyn's lack of documentation I generally check their source to use internal examples to check my samples. I've found this sample from searching [WithBaseList](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwsOz21s3UAhUK6YMKHegJBBcQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsource.roslyn.io%2FMicrosoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces%2FR%2Fc8faa1f006ed068e.html&usg=AFQjCNHQV-w58xY8gf10G-rlUdVLdiDuGA&sig2=tMo0BLB71p71u2wPAL3Dbw)

```
var implementedInterfaceTypeSyntax = extractedInterfaceSymbol.TypeParameters.Any()
            ? SyntaxFactory.GenericName(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(extractedInterfaceSymbol.Name),
                SyntaxFactory.TypeArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(extractedInterfaceSymbol.TypeParameters.Select(p => SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(p.Name)))))
            : SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(extractedInterfaceSymbol.Name);

var baseList = typeDeclaration.BaseList ?? SyntaxFactory.BaseList();
var updatedBaseList = baseList.WithTypes(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(baseList.Types.Union(new[] { SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(implementedInterfaceTypeSyntax) })));
```

In this instance they are using the symbol to generate the type.